# Listening socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I got a strange problem, I never actually expirienced this before, here is the code of the server (client is firefox in this case), the way I create it:

```
_Socket = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
_Socket.Bind( new IPEndPoint( Settings.IP, Settings.Port ) );
_Socket.Listen( 1000 );
_Socket.Blocking = false;
```

the way i accept connection:

```
while( _IsWorking )
{
    if( listener.Socket.Poll( -1, SelectMode.SelectRead ) )
    {
        Socket clientSocket = listener.Socket.Accept();
        clientSocket.Blocking = false;
        clientSocket.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, true );
    }
}
```

So I'm expecting it hang on listener.Socket.Poll till new connection comes, but after first one comes it hangs on poll forever. I tried to poll it constantly with smaller delay, let's say 10 microseconds, then it never goes in SelectMode.SelectRead. I guess it maybe somehow related on client's socket reuse? Maybe I don't shutdown client socket propertly and client(firefox) decides to use an old socket?

I disconnect client socket this way:

```
Context.Socket.Shutdown( SocketShutdown.Both ); // context is just a wrapper around socket
Context.Socket.Close();
```

What may cause that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered accepting remote clients asynchronously? I [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740664/1-second-tcplistener-pending-accepttcpclient-lag/2741075#2741075) recently on `TCPListener`, but the same pattern can be used for on the `Socket` Class.

I have never seen this used before to check if a client is available to connect:

```
listener.Socket.Poll( -1, SelectMode.SelectRead ) )
```

I had a look inside the `Sockets.TCPListener.Pending()` method using .NET reflector and they have this instead, maybe you can try it:

```
public bool Pending()
{
    if (!this.m_Active)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("net_stopped"));
    }
    return this.m_ServerSocket.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead);
}
```

Just bear in mind that according to MSDN the [TCPListener.Pending()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.pending.aspx) method is non-blocking so not sure if it helps you 100%?

Comment: I think I found the reason for behavour I described, this was that I didn't disconnect client socket after it's being processed and after that new connection for some reason could not be made, I guess it's some how related to the client's (firefox in this case) desire to use one socket (if it wasn't closed by server) till it's possible.

Comment: actually that guy in the question you mentioned did it completely wrong :) and i actually didn't mention he had sleep between pending checks, i dunno really for which purpose he was doing this listening in non-blocking manner..